# Shorten this in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Let `x = [1,...,t]` be a vector with `t` components and `A` and `P` arrays. I asked myself whether there is any chance to shorten this, as it looks very cumbersome:

```
for n = 1:t
    for m = 1:n
        H(n,m) = A(n,m) + x(n) * P(n,m)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion: `bsxfun(@times,x,P) + A;`

e.g.

```
A = rand(3);
P = rand(3);
x = rand(3,1);

for n = 1:3
    for m = 1:3
        H(n,m) = A(n,m) + x(n) * P(n,m);
    end
end 


H2 = bsxfun(@times,x,P) + A;

%//Check that they're the same
all(H(:) == H2(:))
```

returns

```
ans =  1
```

**EDIT:**
Amro is right! To make the second loop is dependent on the first use `tril`:

```
H2 = tril(bsxfun(@times,x,P) + A);
```

Are the matrices square btw because that also creates other problems

Comment: are you sure this is correct? the second loop in the question is `for m = 1:n` not `for m = 1:t` (so it depends on the first loop counter), unless that was a typo... OP please double check, I've been trying to vectorize that instead!

Comment: yep easily fixed :) +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Like I pointed out in the comments, unless it was a typo mistake, the second for-loop counter depends on that of the first for-loop...

In case it was intentional, I came up with the following solution:

```
% some random data
t = 10;
x = (1:t)';
A = rand(t,t);
P = rand(t,t);

% double for-loop
H = zeros(t,t);
for n = 1:t
    for m = 1:n
        H(n,m) = A(n,m) + x(n) * P(n,m);
    end
end

% vectorized using linear-indexing
[a,b] = ndgrid(1:t,1:t);
idx = sub2ind([t t], nonzeros(tril(a)), nonzeros(tril(b)));
xidx = nonzeros(tril(a));
HH = zeros(t);
HH(tril(true(t))) = A(idx) + x(xidx).*P(idx);

% check the results are the same
assert(isequal(H,HH))
```

---

I like [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917157/97160)'s solution better. The only advantage here is that I do not compute unnecessary values (since the upper half of the matrix is zeros), while the other solution computes the full matrix and then cut back the extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`tril(A + P.*repmat(x',1,t))`

EDIT. This is for when x is row vector.
If x is a column vector, then use `tril(A + P.*repmat(x,t,1))`

---

If your example code is correct, then H(i,j) = 0 for any j > i, e.g. X(1,2).
For `t = 3` for example, you would have.

```
H = 

'A(1,1) + x(1) * P(1,1)'                          []                          []
'A(2,1) + x(2) * P(2,1)'    'A(2,2) + x(2) * P(2,2)'                          []
'A(3,1) + x(3) * P(3,1)'    'A(3,2) + x(3) * P(3,2)'    'A(3,3) + x(3) * P(3,3)'
```

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be

```
H = A + x*P
```

This may not be a working solution, you'll have to check conformability of arrays and vectors, and make sure that you're using the correct multiplication, but this should be enough to point you in the right direction.  If you're new to Matlab be aware that vectors can be either `1xn` or `nx1`, ie row and column vectors are different species unlike in so many programming languages.  If `x` isn't what you want on the rhs, you may want its transpose, `x'` in Matlab.

Matlab is, from one point of view, an array language, explicit loops are often unnecessary and frequently not even a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range for second loop is `1:n`, you can take the lower triangle parts of matrices `A` and `P` for calculation

```
H = bsxfun(@times,x(:),tril(P)) + tril(A);
```